# Extract from List of JSON

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-iceberg

I have a string field: `[{"et": "AS","ct":"MC"},{"et": "AT","ct":"TC"}, {"et": "AQ","ct":"EC"}]`

I want to get the "**ct**" column values to be combined together as part of new column something like **MC_TC_EC**

The table is Iceberg Table.
I have looked into https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json to figure out how to extract the values from each json of the list but all in vain.
Table name: custTable
String field: custDetail
New Field: custInitials

Comment: "I want" and "I need" are no questions and SO is no code writing service. You need to show what you have tried and to explain what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I have tried using from_json and json_tuple as available from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json but somehow could not figure out how i deal with the list of json.

Comment: so you want a new column with MC or TC or EC in it ? (or any value associated to "ct"?) (& why not call it ct_value?)

Comment: Yes, the new column is basically ct_values. And the requirement is to get all the ct values in the list json in one column as mentioned(MC_TC_EC)

Comment: the whole point of using formats like JSON is that it allows for a variable number of attributes. In traditional table design you would need to place "ct values" into a many-to-one table relationship (because one source row has (in the example) 3 different values). Why create concatenated string column with those values? That is a messy approach and one not likely to be either adaptable or easy to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is untested but might do what you have asked for:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  array_join(
    transform(
      parsed, 
      x -> x.ct
    ), 
    '_'
  ) as custInitials 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      from_json(custDetail, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<et: STRING, ct: STRING>>') as parsed 
    FROM 
      custTable
  ) t
```